# Switch nth-child with media queries

Tags: html, css

I have the following simple grid using `nth-child`:

```css
.grid section {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
}
.grid section:nth-child(3n+3) {
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .grid section {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
  }
  .grid section:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin: auto;
  }
  .grid section:nth-child(even) {
    margin: 0 0 2% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

</div>
```

On the desktop version of the code, the grid displays 3 boxes in a row.

When the screen size reaches 600px, it drops down to 2 boxes in a row. Is there a way I can switch off `nth-child(3n+3)` within the media query?

Comment: Include the nth-child in a query that turns it on above 600px - like `@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {`

Comment: That is genius, thank you! Please add this as your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `nth-child` rule in a query that turns in on on screens above 600px

Like so:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .grid section:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin: 0 0 2% 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this ?

```css
.grid section {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
}
.grid section:nth-child(3n+3) {
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .grid section {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
  }
  .grid section:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
  }
  .grid section:nth-child(even) {
    margin: 0 0 2% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

  <section class="box">
    <p>I'm a box</p>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith You can just click "Run code snippet" in the answer itself.

Comment: @Oriol I was building the fiddle to answer the question, when i returned to the question I saw Vincent already answered it so I just put it here, IDC if its in his answer or not.